# chromedriver fails in Travis

Tags: php, docker, webdriver, travis-ci, chrome-web-driver

We're using chromedriver together with Facebook PHP webdriver in our test suite. It works fine locally, but one test always fails on Travis with the message

```
Curl error thrown for http DELETE to /session/44225d310546d29b1e0adc20ed29a2a0
Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

Is this a known problem? I've read the chrome uses Linux containers it self and that this could lead to conflicts?

Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use headless Firefox with Selenium instead. It will work.